# Is there a equivalent of XPath/JsonPath for unstructured text?

Tags: filter, vscode-extensions

I'm looking for some a simple way to filter unstructured text files (logs). It would be perfect to have some VSCode extension or online tool for simple text filtering like JsonPath does, without creating complicated RegEx.

Expected output:

- Input text lines starting with a specific word
- Input text lines containing specific word

Do you guys use any simple tool that can help with this?

Comment: Ask an AI like ChatGPT to generate the regular expressions for you and you can learn from the results. No need for any other tools from now on.

Comment: VS Code extension 'Filter Lines' is something that meets my expectations.

Comment: If that's your choice, you should post/accept your own answer below to close the discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code extension 'Filter Lines' is something that meets my expectations.